# How to retrieve the textColor attribute from a custom style

Tags: android, android-styles

I defined a custom style in *styles.xml*:

```
<style name="MyCustomStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/my_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_custom_color</item>
</style>
```

and `my_custom_color` is defined in *colors.xml*:

```
<color name="my_custom_color">#202224</color>
```

I'm trying to apply those values to a `TextView` programmatically:

```
void setStyle(Activity activity, TextView textView, int styleResId) {
    int[] attrs = { android.R.attr.background, android.R.attr.textColor };
    TypedArray style = activity.obtainStyledAttributes(styleResId, attrs);
    textView.setBackground(style.getDrawable(0));
    int color = style.getColor(1, -1);
    textView.setTextColor(color);
    style.recycle();
}
```

The part that sets the background is working fine but for some reason `color` is always `-1` instead of being the color I defined in colors.xml.

What am I doing wrong?